# How to permanently enable top bar, even in fullscreen mode

Tags: gnome, gui, fullscreen, extension, top-bar

I have the [Peek Top Bar Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6048/peek-top-bar-on-fullscreen/), but that only partially solves my problem. I'd like for the top bar to be permanently visible, even in fullscreen mode. Preferrably, I'd like for applications to only consider the remainder of the screen when going into fullscreen (so that the top bar doesn't hide any of the app's controls), but I'll take what I can get, even if it's overlaying the top bar over the application. Is there a way to enable that?

Comment: That's a question that I am also seeking an answer for. I tested with **Dash to Panel** extension's various **Panel Intellihide** options, but they didn't help.